# Get build time with Gradle Kotlin DSL

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

In my Gradle script's `build` task, I want to get the current timestamp whenever I build my project and save it to a file in my project's resource directory. If I understand correctly, I should be able to call Java methods to achieve this, something like (in Kotlin):

```kotlin
val timestamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss").format(Date())
```

Attempting to import my script into IntelliJ fails with unresolved reference errors (`SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`).

Using the fully qualified name does not work either (`java.util.Date`); IntelliJ shows that it tries to treat `java` as the `java` plugin.

My `build.gradle.kts` looks like this:

```kotlin
plugins {
    `java-library`
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.10"
    java
    idea
    application
    ... other plugins ...
    
}

tasks.build {
    val timestamp = SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy_hh-mm").format(Date())
}

... other configuration ...
```

How can I properly use those references? Am I missing a specific plugin, or do I need to be taking a whole different approach?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried adding an import statement to the top of your `build.gradle.kts` file?

Most likely `java` refers to the identically named task, because you're inside the tasks scope.

```kotlin
import java.util.Date
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

plugins {
   ...
}

tasks.build {
    val timestamp = SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy_hh-mm").format(Date())
}

... other configuration ...
```

Instead of using the `java.util.Date` class, I recommend taking a look at the newer `java.time.Instant` class instead.

Comment: I tried that first, but I just realized I didn't put it all the way at the top of the file... duh. This works, thank you!

Comment: Another option would be to import `import java.time.LocalDateTime` and `import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` and then use `LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))` (choose your pattern)